# How to refresh an element outside form with h:command ajax in jsf2?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

How can I refresh an element outside the form through ajax render .

```
<ui:repeat var="o">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGroup id="someid">
       ...
        </h:panelGroup>

        <div>
            <h:commandButton action="#{o.doSomething}">
                <f:ajax event="action" render="someid :rehreshthistoo" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </div>
    <h:form>
</ui:repeat>

 <h:panelGroup id="rehreshthistoo">
       ...
 </h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Although it would **only** work if the `<h:panelGroup id="rehreshthistoo">` is not already by itself in *another* `UINamingContainer` component and also if you haven't changed the default JSF naming container separator of `:` to something else such as `_` or `-`.

The ultimate answer should be found in the JSF-generated HTML source. Open the page in the browser, rightclick and *View Source*, locate the generated `<span>` element of `<h:panelGroup id="rehreshthistoo">` in there and then use exactly its ID in your `<f:ajax render>` with the naming container separator as prefix. If it contains an auto-generated ID of some `UINamingContainer` parent, then you should give that parent component a fixed ID as well.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Ajax rendering of content outside form](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentOutsideForm)